# IB HL Math, proving that a function is greater than $1$, for all $x>0$

Tags: functions, solution-verification

The function $f$ is given by $$f(x)= \frac {3^x + 1}{3^x - 3^{-x}}$$ for $x>0$.
Show that $f(x)>1$ for all $x>0$

Hi all, I think I have solved this question but was having trouble proving this in a succinct and intuitive way. I would appreciate any help you might have to offer.

Thanks,
T

Comment: We have $f(x)= \frac {3^x + 1}{3^x - 3^{-x}}=\frac {3^{2x}+3^x}{3^{2x}-1}=\frac {3^{2x}-1+1+3^x}{3^{2x}-1}=1+\frac {3^x+1}{3^{2x}-1}>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $t=3^x$, this is equivalent to
$$\frac{t+1}{t-1/t}>1 $$
for all $t>1$. Some simple manipulations of the fraction expression take us to
$$ 1<\frac{t+1}{t-1/t}=\frac{t(t+1)}{t^2-1}=\frac{t(t+1)}{(t+1)(t-1)}=\frac{t}{t-1}=1+\frac1{t-1}$$
an as $\frac1{t-1}$ is positive for $t>1$, we are done.

Comment: This is basically what I did, but you went a step with the parcellation of the fraction. Are you a seasoned veteran and knew that:
$\frac{x}{x-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{x-1}$ ? 
Or did you use partial fractions? Either way, very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Well for $x>0$ we have $\begin{cases}3^x+1>3^x\\3^x-3^{-x}<3^x\end{cases}\ $ thus  $\text{num}>\text{den}>0$ and the quotient is $>1$.

You can also do $(\text{num}-\text{den})=3^x+1-3^x+3^{-x}=1+3^{-x}>0$ for the same conclusion.